# How to place big matrix in page (A4)?

Tags: matrices

I have this matrix and it is very big for contain in page (A4 paper). How do I make to place in page?

```
\[A = \begin{bmatrix}
%C1
m &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}} &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}x_{i1}^{C_1}} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}x_{iq}^{C_1}} &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2x_{iq}^{C_1}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_1})^2} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
%C2
0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}} &0 &\cdots &0\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}} &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}x_{i1}^{C_2}}  &0 &\cdots &0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}x_{iq}^{C_2}} &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2x_{iq}^{C_2}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_2})^2} &0 &\cdots &0\\
%R
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}}\\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}}& \sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{R})^2} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}x_{i1}^{R}}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}x_{iq}^{R}} &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{R})^2x_{iq}^{R}} &\cdots &\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{R})^2} 
\label{eq:matrix_A}
\end{bmatrix}\]
```

Comment: How wide is the text block, and which font size do you use?

Comment: Incidentally, `\sum` does *not* take an argument; writing `\sum{...}` adds clutter, nothing else.

Comment: of-topic: your matrix is not numbered, so label is surplus ...

Comment: The multitudes of `\vdots` and `\cdots` are quite confusing, by the way. Should some of the `\vdots` maybe be `\ddots`?

Comment: font size 12pt, it should is enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming margins of 2.5cm and a font size of 10pt, it suffices to omit all limits of summation (since they're all identical, stating the limits explicitly in the matrix provides no crucial information...) and to reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace by 50% or so.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt}    % default: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % more relaxed vertical spacing
A = \begin{bmatrix}
%C1
m &\sum x_{i1}^{C_1} &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{C_1} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
\sum x_{i1}^{C_1} &\sum (x_{i1}^{C_1})^2 &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{C_1}x_{i1}^{C_1} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
\sum x_{i1}^{C_1}x_{iq}^{C_1} &\sum (x_{i1}^{C_1})^2x_{iq}^{C_1} &\cdots &\sum (x_{iq}^{C_1})^2 &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
%C2
0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sum x_{i1}^{C_2} &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{C_2} &0 &\cdots &0\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sum x_{i1}^{C_2} &\sum (x_{i1}^{C_2})^2 &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{C_2}x_{i1}^{C_2}  &0 &\cdots &0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sum x_{i1}^{C_2}x_{iq}^{C_2} &\sum (x_{i1}^{C_2})^2x_{iq}^{C_2} &\cdots &\sum (x_{iq}^{C_2})^2 &0 &\cdots &0\\
%R
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sum x_{i1}^{R} &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{R}\\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sum x_{i1}^{R}& \sum (x_{i1}^{R})^2 &\cdots &\sum x_{iq}^{R}x_{i1}^{R}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sum x_{i1}^{R}x_{iq}^{R} &\sum (x_{i1}^{R})^2x_{iq}^{R} &\cdots &\sum (x_{iq}^{R})^2
\label{eq:matrix_A} % huh?!
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am working in a template of a journal, but it has not margin especified.

Answer (score 1):

I can fit your matrix on page with help of two tricks:

- for equation I use smaller font
- with macro `\adjustwidth` from package \changepage` I enlarge horizontal space for matrix -- so it protrude to outer text margin (if this doesn't allowed, then my suggestion will not help you :-( )

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\sumim{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}


\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\marginparwidth}\small
\[A = \begin{bmatrix}
%C1
m &\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_1}} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{C_1}} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_1}} &\sumim{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{C_1}x_{i1}^{C_1}} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_1}x_{iq}^{C_1}} &\sumim{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2x_{iq}^{C_1}} &\cdots &\sumim{(x_{iq}^{C_1})^2} &0 &\cdots &0 &0 &\cdots &0\\
%C2
0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_2}} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{C_2}} &0 &\cdots &0\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_2}} &\sumim{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{C_2}x_{i1}^{C_2}}  &0 &\cdots &0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 &\cdots &0 &\sumim{x_{i1}^{C_2}x_{iq}^{C_2}} &\sumim{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2x_{iq}^{C_2}} &\cdots &\sumim{(x_{iq}^{C_2})^2} &0 &\cdots &0\\
%R
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &m &\sumim{x_{i1}^{R}} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{R}}\\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sumim{x_{i1}^{R}}& \sumim{(x_{i1}^{R})^2} &\cdots &\sumim{x_{iq}^{R}x_{i1}^{R}}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 &0 &\cdots &0 &\cdots &0 &\sumim{x_{i1}^{R}x_{iq}^{R}} &\sumim{(x_{i1}^{R})^2x_{iq}^{R}} &\cdots &\sumim{(x_{iq}^{R})^2}
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

I try to introduce `ddots` in place where I guess that should be used.

Option showframe is only to show page layout. In real use it had to be omitted.
Result is:

[image]